# PHP get a div from page x

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I wanna extract some html from page Y

```
for example site is
<head>xxxx</head>
<body>....<div id="ineedthis_code"> </div> ...</body>
```

it is possible to do this file_get_contents ?!
i need only that div nothing else

Comment: Have a look at this and use one of these libraries 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php

Comment: The above comment is a good answer to what you need. You say you need only a particular <div>, but you're going to need to collect the entire page anyways. It's then you can use DOM or phpQuery to specifically target your extracted content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a special library (which is the best way in most cases), you can use the explode-function:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div id="YOUR ID HERE">' , $content ); // So you will get two array elements

$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] ); // "1" depends, if you have more elements with this id (theoretical) 

echo $second_step[0]; // You will get the first element with the content within the DIV :)
```

Please note, it's only an example without error handling. It also works onlny on a special case; not if the html structure ist changing. Even simple spaces can break this code. So you should better use a parsing library ;-)